# PySpark DataFrame to JSON for API post request

Tags: json, dataframe, pyspark, formatting

I am trying to convert PySpark dataframe from Hive table to JSON in a particular format to send it as a data to API via POST method. I somehow cannot get "ValuesListIds" in the JSON. Appreciate if anyone can come up with a solution.

Dataframe:

[image]

JSON Format I am looking for is :

{
"Id": 0,
"Results":[2261730],
"Submit_Results": {
"ValuesListIds": [58895]
},
"Value": 99,
"Source": {
"ValuesListIds": [43861]
},
"Date": "9/30/2020"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```py
df.show()
# +----+---------+----------------+-------+--------+---------+
# | Id | results | submit_results | Value | Source |    Date |
# +----+---------+----------------+-------+--------+---------+
# |   0|[2261730]|         [58911]|     99|[439012]|9/30/2020|
# +----+---------+----------------+-------+--------+---------+

list_of_rows = df.collect()
# [Row(Date='9/30/2020', Id=0, Source=[439012], Value=99, results=[2261730], submit_results=[58911])]

d = list_of_rows[0].asDict()
# {'Date': '9/30/2020',
#  'Id': 0,
#  'Source': [439012],
#  'Value': 99,
#  'results': [2261730],
#  'submit_results': [58911]}

# adjust the dict in-place
d["submit_results"] = {"ValuesListIds": d["submit_results"]}
d["Source"] = {"ValuesListIds": d["Source"]}

# now it looks like this:
# {'Date': '9/30/2020',
#  'Id': 0,
#  'Source': {'ValuesListIds': [439012]},
#  'Value': 99,
#  'results': [2261730],
#  'submit_results': {'ValuesListIds': [58911]}}

# `requests` will automatically convert the dict to JSON
requests.post(url, data=d)
```

Comment: Thank you for trying out... I need the keyword "ValueListIDs" for "Submit_results" and "Source" fields. These 2 are nested JSON objects.

Comment: Uhh sorry, I missed that part, and for some reason I thought you were talking about `pandas`, not `pyspark`, so I guess my answer is pretty useless right now. Could you update the question with the `pyspark` code that you use to generate the dataframe?

Comment: I kind of resolved the issue, however stuck on one more part. I get the final result in rdd, but need to json.dump into a body of a POST request. Any idea?                       mdf = spark.sql('select 0 as Id, array(2261730)  as results, array(58895) as submit_results, 45 as Value, array(43861) as Source, "9/30/2020" as Date from table limit 1')

new = mdf.select("Id","Results", F.struct(F.col('results').alias('ValuesListIDs')).alias('results'), "Value", F.struct(F.col('Source').alias('ValuesListIDs')).alias('Source'), "Date")


new.toJSON()

Comment: Ok cool! `.toJSON()` returns an RDD, so you need to call `.collect()` on it to turn it into a list of JSON strings, or you can use `.first()` to get just the first element. Then you need something like `response = requests.post(url, json=your_json_from_rdd)`.

Comment: Ok I have rewritten the answer, now it should make way more sense. Since it looks like you only need the single row of the result, I did `df.collect()` immediately so I could work on a plain Python `dict` which seems to me like less of an overkill(?) than creating a new DataFrame with struct columns.

Comment: That looks great!! Thank you for the solution :) Appreciate it!!

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help. Once you confirm it works, please mark the answer as the accepted one. Cheers!